# Barplot of several categorical variables

Tags: r, plot, categorical-data

I have a subset `data3` of 50 factors and I want to make a barplot of all of them. I know how to do it one by one but I would like to know if there is a way of doing it for the whole dataset at once:

```
barplot(prop.table(table(data3$factor1)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to loop over the columns, get the `proportions` and plot it in from the `list`, save it in a `pdf`

```
pdf("testing.pdf")
lst1 <- lapply(data3, function(x) barplot(proportions(table(x))))
dev.off()
```

---

Or another option is to convert to 'long' format with `pivot_longer` and plot with `ggplot`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
data3 %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = everything()) %>%
    count(name, value = factor(value)) %>%
    group_by(name) %>%
    mutate(prop = n/sum(n)) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = name, y = prop, fill = value)) + 
        geom_col()
```